# How to add new Column to Android SQLite Database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have one problem with Android `SQLite` database.

I have one table which contains one field.StudentFname
and that application is working fine with Android 2.3.1 and now if I add another field then my application is not working properly.

Can anyone help me who knows database very well,

Answer (score 201, accepted):

you can use `ALTER TABLE` function on your `onUpgrade()` method, like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  // If you need to add a column
  if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
     db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN new_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
  }
}
```

Obviously, the SQLite will differ depending on the column definition.

Comment: hi! i have tried this i have used on upgrate method and inside that i have put alter table query as well.but still i am not able to add new column to the database..but ya when i write a query to add new column and renamed the database and table name both than i am able to add new column..but with the help of alter table method i am not able to do so..renaming database and table is not the desired task..it should be working with alter table..still i am not able to do it with alter table method..

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy sorry for late reply.

you can use this method
db.execSQL("UPDATE table SET key = key + 1 WHERE name=?", new String[] {name});

Comment: Don't forget to increase Database version, otherwise onUpgrade() will not be called.

Increase the version number in the below code, which will be present in the constructor of the class which extends the SQLiteOpenHelper class.
super(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int newVersion)

Comment: App freezes and i have many message like this on log cat: The connection pool for database '+data+user+0+com..._db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 1 (main) with flags 0x5 for. Why this happened?

Comment: `if (newVersion > oldVersion) ` condition is unnecessary here because `onUpgrade` itself only gets called when this condition met i.e new version is greater than  the old version

Answer (score 33):

I came across this thread when needing help on my own app, but saw issues with many of the answers. I would recommend doing the following:

```
private static final String DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_1 = "ALTER TABLE "
    + TABLE_TEAM + " ADD COLUMN " + COLUMN_COACH + " string;";

private static final String DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_2 = "ALTER TABLE "
    + TABLE_TEAM + " ADD COLUMN " + COLUMN_STADIUM + " string;";

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
         db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_1);
    }
    if (oldVersion < 3) {
         db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_2);
    }
}
```

You want to make sure the code will work when users upgrade more than 1 version and that the update statement only runs the one upgrade it is needed. For a bit more on this, check out this [blog](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/how-android-sqlite-onupgrade).

Comment: what to do if we want to create altered column with default String value??

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way to do this is to add some `SQL to the onUpgrade()` method in your `SQLiteOpenHelper class`. Something like:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    // If you need to add a new column
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE student ADD COLUMN student_rollno INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but still i am not able to add new column by using alter table method in on upgrate method.

Comment: hi! i have tried this i have used on upgrate method and inside that i have put alter table query as well.but still i am not able to add new column to the database..but ya when i write a query to add new column and renamed the database and table name both than i am able to add new column..but with the help of alter table method i am not able to do so..renaming database and table is not the desired task..it should be working with alter table..still i am not able to do it with alter table method

Comment: @user370305 should i have to add new column in tablle create statement for new users who install the app first time?

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps a slightly more elegant approach using switch instead of if/then that will upgrade from any schema to the most recent schema...

Here's also a decent page on the syntax for altering a table: http://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-alter-table-syntax-examples

```
public static final String TABLE_TEAM = "team";
public static final String COLUMN_COACH = "coach";
public static final String COLUMN_STADIUM = "stadium";


private static final String DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_TO_V2 = "ALTER TABLE "
    + TABLE_TEAM + " ADD COLUMN " + COLUMN_COACH + " TEXT;";

private static final String DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_TO_V3 = "ALTER TABLE "
    + TABLE_TEAM + " ADD COLUMN " + COLUMN_STADIUM + " TEXT;";


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    switch (oldVersion)
    {
        case 1:
            //upgrade from version 1 to 2
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_TO_V2);
        case 2:
            //upgrade from version 2 to 3
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_TO_V3);

        //and so on.. do not add breaks so that switch will
        //start at oldVersion, and run straight through to the latest

    }

}
```

Comment: This is the way to handle multiple upgrades. Checking which version comes from!

Comment: If you go from version 1 to 3 directly (if someone doesn't auto-update the app), you won't reach case 2.

Comment: @TyMarc-- Yes, it will upgrade to versions 2 then 3.  The switch uses the old version.  So, in your example, the old version is 1.  The code will then run case 1, which upgrades from versions 1 to 2, and then will run case 2 (since there is no break;), which upgrades from 2 to 3.  It's all right there in the description.

Answer (score 5):

I have done the following approach, it is resovled for me

**if DB version : 6**

```
Ex : There is a table with 5 columns
```

**When you upgrade to : 7** ( I am adding 1 new column in the 3 tables)

```
 1. We need to add the columns when creating a table

 2. onUpgrade method:

 if (oldVersion < 7) 
 { 
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_ADD_PAPER_PAID);
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_LAST_UPLOADED);
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_PAPER_LABEL); 
 }
```

Where : "DATABASE_ALTER_ADD_PAPER_PAID" is query.

```
EX: public static final String DATABASE_ALTER_ADD_PAPER_PAID = "ALTER TABLE "
                + TableConstants.MY_PAPERS_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + COLUMN_PAPER_PAID + " TEXT;";
```

After above two operation it will works fine for the fresh install user and app upgrade user

Answer (score 3):

@Aamirkhan.i think you would have solved the problem you mentioned in the comments long back ago.i think you didn't increase the data base version. or else the answers here are straight forward.i am writing this because it might help anyone who hasn't increased or changed their data base version number when they are altering a table.

Comment: yes,changing database name and unistalling application and reinstalling it again would solve the problem

Comment: @Aamirkhan, please move the check to the next answer so the more clear solution is available to the public.

Answer (score 3):

I think we should not check condition like that

```
 if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
 }
```

because if we use this , it means every time when we increase the database version then onUpdrade()  will call and condition will be true , so we should check like that

```
if(oldVersion==1) 
{

}
```

so in this case if old version is  2 then condition will be false and user with old version 2 will not update the database(which user wants only for version 1), because for those users database had already updated .

Answer (score 2):

To add a new column to the table you need to use `ALTER`. In android you can add the new column inside the `onUpgrade()`.

You may be wonder, how `onUpgrade()` will add the new column?

When you implementing a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, you need to call superclass constructor: `super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);` in your class constructor. There I have passed `1` for version.

When I changed the version `1` to above(`2` or greater), `onUpgrade()` will invoked. And perform the SQL modifications which I intend to do.
My class constructor after changed the version:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);//version changed from 1 to 2
}
```

SQL modifications checks like this, superclass constructor compares the version of the stored SQLite db file with the version that I passed to `super()`. If these(previous and now) version numbers are different `onUpgrade()` gets invoked.

Code should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // add new columns to migrate to version 2
    if (oldVersion < 2) { 
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "ADD COLUMN school VARCHAR(250)");
    }
    // add new columns to migrate to version 3
    if (oldVersion < 3) { 
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "ADD COLUMN age INTEGER");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change in your code

> private  final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

to

> private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =2;

Answer (score 2):

first, increment the database version number. and then in `onUpgrade` method, you can check if the column exists already if not then only add the column

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   if(!existsColumnInTable(db, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME)){
      db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN COLUMN_NAME INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
 } 
 }

private boolean existsColumnInTable(SQLiteDatabase inDatabase, String inTable, String columnToCheck) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        // Query 1 row
        cursor = inDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + inTable + " LIMIT 0", null);

        // getColumnIndex() gives us the index (0 to ...) of the column - otherwise we get a -1
        if (cursor.getColumnIndex(columnToCheck) != -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    } catch (Exception Exp) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) cursor.close();
    }
}
```

this method is extracted from this link [Checking if a column exists in an application database in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719594/checking-if-a-column-exists-in-an-application-database-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I came across link while searching for the same issue. It explains how to use upgrade. 
https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/how-android-sqlite-onupgrade

it explains why to use this below code

```
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
             db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_1);
        }
        if (oldVersion < 3) {
             db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a new column on a table is add some SQL to the onUpgrade() method in SQLiteOpenHelper class. Like:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    switch (oldVersion) {
        case 1:
            db.execSQL(SQL_MY_TABLE);

        case 2:
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN myNewColumn TEXT");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed no answers look for the existence of a column:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MY_TABLE, null);
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MY_NEW_COLUMN);
if (columnIndex < 0) {
   database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + MY_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + MY_NEW_COLUMN + " TEXT");
}
```