# Android SQLiteDatabase inserting error

Tags: android, sqlite

some problems with my simple accountbook code.

I want to insert a row when I click the save button.

I checked my table created successfully.

```
save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mDbOpenHelper.open();

            try{
            mDbOpenHelper.insertColumn(
                    rButton, 
                    mEditTexts[1].getText().toString().trim(), 
                    spinnerSelected, 
                    mEditTexts[0].getText().toString().trim());
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("TAG","error");
            }

            mDbOpenHelper.close();
            mCursor.close();

        }

    });
```

insertColumn( )

```
// Insert DB
        public long insertColumn(String cashORcard, String amount, String category, String detail){
            mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Database.CreateDB.CASH, cashORcard);
            values.put(Database.CreateDB.AMOUNT, amount);
            values.put(Database.CreateDB.CATEGORY, category);
            values.put(Database.CreateDB.DETAIL, detail);

            return mDB.insert(Database.CreateDB.TABLENAME, null, values);

        }
```

define of my database table

```
public class Database {

public static final class CreateDB implements BaseColumns{
    public static String firstCash="0";
    public static String firstAccount="0";
    public static String allMoney="0";
    public static final String CASH="cash";
    public static final String CATEGORY="category";
    public static final String DETAIL="detail";
    public static final String AMOUNT="0";
    public static final String ID="0";
    public static final String TABLENAME="Accountbook";
    public static final String CREATE=
            "CREATE TABLE "+TABLENAME
            +" ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +" CASH text not null , "
            +" AMOUNT text not null , "
            +" CATEGORY text not null , "
            +" DETAIL text , "
            +" firstCash text not null , "
            +" firstAccount text not null , "
            +" allMoney text not null );";  
    }
}
```

log

```
04-17 02:53:11.471: E/SQLiteLog(877): (1) near "0": syntax error
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877): Error inserting cash=cash detail=asdf category=salary 0=567
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "0": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Accountbook(cash,detail,category,0) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at com.android.accountbook_edit.DbOpenHelper.insertColumn(DbOpenHelper.java:82)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at com.android.accountbook_edit.Income$3.onClick(Income.java:99)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-17 02:53:11.501: E/SQLiteDatabase(877):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

need more code, plz let me know!
Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you want to insert column into your table ? Because the logic which you have written is for the inserting records into the table not for inserting column in database.

Comment: Check the definition of your statics AMOUNT and ID -- they should be `"amount"` and "`_id`", not `"0"`.

Comment: Take a look to this answer...[this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291673/how-to-add-new-column-to-android-sqlite-database

Hope it help you..

Comment: Thanq all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are inserting *rows* not *columns*.

Then, the error in your log is very clear

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "0": ... INSERT INTO Accountbook(cash,detail,category,0) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ...
```

You are trying to insert a value into an invalid column name: **0**

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String AMOUNT="0"
```

This should be

```
public static final String AMOUNT="AMOUNT"
```

The result of what you are trying to insert into a column named "0"

Comment: May I know what is wrong with this answer? Why it was down voted?

Comment: I'm fairly sure its a person who dislikes me and votes me down when he sees my posts.  Happens whenever we post in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

See error is `0=567` . Here your column name is in `integer` type. So this is error. Colomn name should  be valid. So Just try the following

```
public static final String CREATE=
        "CREATE TABLE "+TABLENAME
        +" (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + CASH +" text not null , "
        + AMOUNT+" text not null , "
        + CATEGORY+" text not null , "
        + DETAIL+" text , "
        + firstCash+" text not null , "
        + firstAccount+" text not null , "
        + allMoney+" text not null );";
```

Instead of this

```
public static final String CREATE=
        "CREATE TABLE "+TABLENAME
        +" ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        +" CASH text not null , "
        +" AMOUNT text not null , "
        +" CATEGORY text not null , "
        +" DETAIL text , "
        +" firstCash text not null , "
        +" firstAccount text not null , "
        +" allMoney text not null );";
```

Also change your

```
firstCash,firstAccount,allMoney,AMOUNT varibales values to be valid string.
```

Like

```
public static String firstCash="firstCash";
public static String firstAccount="firstAccount";
public static String allMoney="allMoney";
public static final String AMOUNT="AMOUNT";
```

Why because column names should be valid.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have passed value of `mEditTexts[0].getText().toString().trim()` to string detail. Check that the value of string detail and `ID Database.CreateDB.DETAIL`. If it's showing "0" then it shoud be "detail".

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your insertion query as below :

You need to also pass the other remaining columns `firstCash,firstAccount,allMoney` values also **because in your Create Table query you have defined its property as NOT NULL.**

> ```
> public long insertColumn(String cashORcard, String amount, String category, String detail,String cashValue,String AccountVal,String money){
>         mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
>         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
>         values.put(Database.CreateDB.CASH, cashORcard);
>         values.put(Database.CreateDB.AMOUNT, amount);
>         values.put(Database.CreateDB.CATEGORY, category);
>         values.put(Database.CreateDB.DETAIL, detail);
>         values.put(Database.CreateDB.firstCash, cashValue);
>         values.put(Database.CreateDB.firstAccount, AccountVal);
>         values.put(Database.CreateDB.allMoney, money);
>         return mDB.insert(Database.CreateDB.TABLENAME, null, values);
>     }
> ```