# Calc new column in table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 3 tables: users, albums, photos. User can have albums, each album have photos.
[image]

I want add at table [photos] new column userId with correct data.
I want not only add empty userId column, but this column must be have value from table albums: userId.

How I can easy todo this?

Comment: what do you mean? `alter table add column` thing ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291673/how-to-add-new-column-to-android-sqlite-database

Comment: I think incorrect set question. Now set some change.

Comment: If `photos.userId` is same as `albums.userId` when `photos.albumId=album.id`, them you are duplicating information! Avoid it! Use views and join queries. This is against normalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two tasks to do :

First, add the column to the table.

Once done, you will want to populate userId column. But, in SQLite, you cannot perform a JOIN in an UPDATE statement.

So you should cut it in four steps (I assume there is only 3 fields in your photos table, adapt it to your one).

First create a temporary table which will contain the final datas

```
CREATE TABLE photos_temp (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    albumId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    userId INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Then, populate the temporary table

```
INSERT INTO photos_temp(id, albumId, userId)
    SELECT photos.id as id,
           photos.albumId as albumId,
           albums.userId as userId
FROM       photos
INNER JOIN albums ON photos.albumId = albums.id;
```

Then, remove the original table

```
DROP TABLE photos;
```

Finally, rename the previous table

```
ALTER TABLE photos_temp RENAME TO photos;
```

Sorry, but no easier way to do this.

Comment: I decided don't use column userId at photos table. But anyway, @Gaëtan thanks for answer.