# Flutter - Modify Sqlite table without deleting database

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter

I am using Sqlite database in Flutter by using sqflite plugin. Following the below mentioned links I am able to successfully create database and perform CRUD operations in it.

[Sqflite Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite)

[Sqflite Tutorial - Youtube Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BwjNEKD8g8&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-Lw6tAs2fGFuXGP13-dWdKsB&index=25)

The problem is, Once the database is created I cannot modify old tables. In order to get a new column in "tabEmployee" table, I must delete the database and recreate it.

```
void _onCreate(Database db, int newVersion) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE tabEmployee($idPk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, employeeName TEXT)");
  }
```

What should I do in order to modify previously created table in sqflite without deleting database ?

Comment: You can add a column to a table with [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

Comment: make a similar function
and call this function only once to alter the table, later you can remove this function
`void alterTable() async {
  await db.execute("ALTER TABLE tabEmployee ADD employeePhone TEXT");
}`

Comment: It's a nice hack. This would be my last approach though. There must be another way also.

Comment: Altering a table in a live application is an anti-pattern.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well I managed to resolve my issue. With some help from dlohani comment and [How to add new Column to Android SQLite Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291673/how-to-add-new-column-to-android-sqlite-database) link.

I created a new method "_onUpgrade" and call it as parameter of "openDatabase" and changed the version number.
Following is my relevant code:

```
initDb() async {
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, 'maindb.db');
    var ourDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 2, onCreate: _onCreate, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);
    return ourDb;
  }

  // UPGRADE DATABASE TABLES
  void _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < newVersion) {
      db.execute("ALTER TABLE tabEmployee ADD COLUMN newCol TEXT;");
    }
  }
```

Comment: what does ALERT do in a query ?

Comment: It's "ALTER" not "ALERT". This command is used to add, delete or modify columns in an existing table.

Comment: @ZainSMJ it needs to add `newCol TEXT` column when you are `CREATE TABLE`. right? Otherwise new user's table doesn't include `newCol` column right?

Comment: @ZainSMJ The condition `if (newVersion > oldVersion)` is always `true` and could cause problems if you use multiple migrations.   
  
You should use exact version checks like `if (oldVersion <  2)`


Example from the docs:
https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/migration_example.md

Comment: Yes @RobDev back then I was doing that way lol. But now as you pointed out the right approach for several migrations we must use exact version checks.