# Flutter - How to update the table structure in Sqflite?

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

My app is in production and I want to manage user data when user updates the app without loss of their data, how can I achieve this with `sqflite`. Explicitly I want to add a column and delete another.

Comment: see https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqflite/openDatabase.html

Comment: Could you please explain more about what you are asking and edit your title.

Comment: In production version I have sqflite version 3, so should I change this version for the next update?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can probably [add a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291673/how-to-add-new-column-to-android-sqlite-database) using raw sql, but sqlite (and thus sqflite) doesn't support dropping a column. For that you would need to do the following:

- increase the database version number
- in `onUpgrade` copy the old database columns to a temporary table
- delete the original table
- create a new table using the original table name but with the right schema
- copy the data from the temp table
- delete the temp table

Sorry, this isn't a full answer, but it is the direction I would go if I were in your situation.