# SQLite Check if column exist or not

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to check columns (not value) at *agregasi* table, if columns exist do something, but if columns does not exist show/print message **'Column does not exist'**.
I could run code below while columns exist:

```
String keywords1={'pesawat','terbang'}; 
String sql1 = "SELECT " + keywords + " FROM agregasi"; //columns exist at agregasi table
Cursor c1 = myDbHelper.rawQuery(sql1, null);
if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
   // i can do something (no problem)
}
```

But i have problem when columns name i change on purpose (to check). What should i do to print error message (in android/java way)?

```
**String keywords2={'psawat','terang'};** 
String sql2 = "SELECT " + keywords + " FROM agregasi"; //columns does not exist at table 
Cursor c2 = myDbHelper.rawQuery(sql2, null);
// what should i do get error message and show/print using toast
```

Comment: Show you table creation code. It appears there's an error.

Comment: First check if cursor c1 or c2 is null or not. If null then print error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a column exists in an application database in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719594/checking-if-a-column-exists-in-an-application-database-in-android)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [`getColumnIndex(String columnName)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)).

```
int index = c2.getColumnIndex("someColumnName");
if (index == -1) {
    // Column doesn't exist
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general method you can use to check whether a particular column exists in a particular table:

```
public boolean isColumnExists(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase,
                              String tableName,
                              String columnToFind) {
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {
        cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(
                "PRAGMA table_info(" + tableName + ")",
                null
        );

        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name");

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);

            if (name.equals(columnToFind)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this it works fine :)

```html
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info("+tableName+")",null);
int value = res.getColumnIndex(fieldName);
```

Comment: This pragma will give you infos about the table. There shouldn't be a Column that is named like the column you are looking for in this cursor.